# Access object's properties inside named query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Is it possible to access an object's property inside a named query?

Here is a sample domain class

```
class Publication {
    String title
    String author
    Date datePublished
    Integer numberOfPages

    static namedQueries = {
        newerPublications {
            //Will throw an error, cannot access a variable declared in a dynamic context.
            gt 'datePublished', this.datePublished
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
newerPublications { Publication newerThan ->
    gt 'datePublished', newerThan.datePublished
}
```

You would then call it as `Publication.newerPublications(referencePublication).list()`